# RVM clone for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know of a good RVM clone on Windows? Are there any efforts afoot to create one?

(I am familiar with Pik. Without going into detail, I've tried it for about a month and it doesn't cut it. I wanted it to work, I really did, but to me anyway it is nowhere close to rvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing besides Pik that I know of is using RVM with Cygwin. Tiplite has [this article](http://www.tiplite.com/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-using-cygwin/) that helps with the install.